# c# windows phone 8.1 differences between debug and release mode compile?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

The generated code for a couple of my UserControl won't compile in Release mode. (no problem in Debug mode) and I have no clue where to look at since it's generated.

```
#pragma checksum "C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\StripBall\StripBall\StripBall.Shared\UserControls\Modes\Escalade.xaml" "{406ea660-64cf-4c82-b6f0-42d48172a799}" "1F4D92492659B77C900C0E6C6C0794B3"
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace StripBall.UserControls
{
    partial class Escalade : global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.UserControl, global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.IComponentConnector
    {
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks"," 4.0.0.0")]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]

        public void Connect(int connectionId, object target)
        {
            this._contentLoaded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

> Error 4   'StripBall.UserControls.Escalade' does not contain a definition for '_contentLoaded' and no extension method '_contentLoaded' accepting a first argument of type 'StripBall.UserControls.Escalade' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Check whether it compiles in debug mode if you select "Rebuild Solution" in the "Build" menu

Comment: Hmm, strange problem, the declaration for the _contentLoaded field is indeed missing.  Spin the restart VS, reboot machine, clean+rebuild project wheel of fortune.  Make sure you don't have another error that caused this one.

Comment: yep **Rebuilding the Solution** did the trick. Thanks.